# web browser for Windows CE 5.0 - problem with installation

Tags: browser, windows-ce

I've got a windows CE device without Internet Explorer installed. I need a browser to test WiFi connection but I cannot find anything. I cannot build the system, I have to use the current one.

I've tried to run Opera, Skyfire and some other less known browsers but none of them works on my device. Opera doesn't support Windows CE (cab file is dedicated to Windows Mobile). 
I've found SkyFire for windows CE (without installer, just an exe file with a couple dlls) but it hangs up during startup.

Is there any distribution of Internet Explorer that can be installed at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, IE has to be baked into the OS (and it may change the license requirement from Core to Pro in doing so).  If you have an image that you cannot change, then you might try something like [MiniMo](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/minimo/).  Of course it may have some dependency that's missing in your CE image (that's probably why Skyfire fails).